# SSRS Report scrolling issue

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, sharepoint, reporting-services, rdl

When scrolling down through a recently deployed SSRS report, the columns become jumbled and I am unable to scroll all the way to the bottom.  I have adjusted the zoom of my browser but this has no effect.  The attached screen shot is what my report looks like on the site while scrolling.  I have tried Chrome and IE.  Chrome is my go to for the reports.

[image]

Comment: What version of Reporting Services are you using? Note that Chrome is only a supported browser for SQL Server 2014 Reporting Services or later. Prior to this only IE, Firefox or Safari are supported.

Comment: Is `CanGrow` set to `True` for this cell?

Comment: Yes CanGrow is set to True.  We areare using SQL Server 2014 Reporting Services

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out the problem, the details row was also set to true for FixedData.  I set it to false and everything works fine